# Разбор ответа в json

Tags: jquery, json, api

Доброго времени! Не могу понять как мне добраться до конкретного элемента присылаемого мне в ответ на мой запрос по api данные приходят в формате jason 
вот [тут](http://api.blitspost.work/public/v1/regions/origin?title=%D0%90%D0%BA) показан пример такого ответа, там в regions массив значений и я не могу добраться до какого либо конкретного знаыения title в массиве побую вот так

```
function ggetmycity() {
var city = document.getElementById("cityin").value;

$.get('https://api.exline.systems/public/v1/regions/origin?title='+city,
    function(data){
    var all=data.regions;
        if (data.success) {

        for (index = 0; index < all.length; ++index) {
            $('#result').html(data.regions[index].title);

        }
    }, "json");
return false;

}
```

Функция запускается с события oninput и в переменную city заносится то что ввел пользователь в инпут, подскажите пожалуйста где я тут ошибся - по идее скрипт в цикле перебирает ответ и помещаяет в блок #result все названия полученных из ответ городов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас не хватает одной закрывающей скобки в запросе (наверное условие if забыли закрыть).

Во-вторых у вас в получаемых данных нет `success`, а значит вы в `if (data.success) {` никогда не попадете.

В-третьих в цикле надо в начале всё собрать в строковую переменную например так

```
var html = ''; 
for (var index = 0; index < all.length; ++index) { 
    html += data.regions[index].title + '<br />'; 
}
```

и потом уже выводить в `result`, иначе у вас выведется только последнее значение маcсива......

И в цикле надо бы `for (var index = 0; ...`

В целом как-то так:

```js
function ggetmycity() {
  var city = document.getElementById("cityin").value;

  $.get('https://api.exline.systems/public/v1/regions/origin?title=' + city,
    function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var all = data.regions;
      var html = '';
    
      for (var index = 0; index < all.length; ++index) {
        html += data.regions[index].title + '<br />';
      }
    
      $('#result').html(html);

    }, "json");
  return false;

}

$(document).on('keyup', '#cityin', function() {
  ggetmycity();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="cityin" value="Ак">
<div id="result"></div>
```

---

А чтоб в `ggetmycity` не писать `var city = document.getElementById("cityin").value;`

Можно передавать элемент, где событие происходит:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#cityin', function(){
    ggetmycity(this);
});
```

функция:

```
function ggetmycity(el) {
    var city = el.value;
    ...
    ...
}
```